# Rename file based on content

Tags: bash, grep, macos-sierra

In macOS Sierra (v. 10.12.6), I have a directory containing many flat-text (.txt) files.  Each file has an unhelpful name such as "untitled text 252.txt".  I would like to know if it's possible to programmatically rename every file based on a code located in the first line of every file.

Every file begins with a section symbol (`§`), a space, a code that always contains a period (`.`), and a space.  The code is usually just numeric, but occasionally there is also a trailing hyphen (`-`) followed by a letter.  For example: `'§ 177.30 '`, or `'§ 60.10-a '`.

I would like to rename every file based on its code, but reformat the code first.  In short, prefix a `P`, strip out the period from the code, and add a trailing `.txt`.  Using the examples above, the file names would be:  `P17730.txt` and `P6010-a.txt`.

At a command prompt, I have figured out how to grep the code from each file:

```
grep -o '^§ [A-Za-z0-9]*\.[A-Za-z0-9\-]* ' *.txt
```

This returns everything from the section symbol to the trailing whitespace (e.g. `'§ 130.65-a '`).

So, the remaining questions are:

1. How do I reformat the grep result to the filename I want (e.g. `P13065-a.txt`); and,
2. How do I combine a file rename operation with the grep?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sed` to extract only digits from the first line (by deleting all non-digits):

```
$ sed -n '1 {s/[^0-9]//g; p;}' <<<"§ 177.30 "
17730
```

and then `find` all `*.txt` files, extract digits, and rename to `P<digits>.txt`. Instead of in-place rename, it's safer to copy the files, renaming on fly, to a target dir:

```
$ mkdir -p /path/to/targetdir
$ find . -name '*.txt' -exec bash -c 'digits=$(sed -n "1{s/[^0-9]//g;p;}" "$1"); cp "$1" "/path/to/targetdir/$newname"' _ {} \;
```

by executing a short `bash` script:

```
#!/bin/bash
digits=$(sed -n "1{s/[^0-9]//g;p;}" "$1")
cp "$1" "/path/to/targetdir/$newname"
```

for each file found by `find` (and given as the first positional parameter, `$1`).

Comment: Please make a copy of your files and try this on the copy only and make sure you have the same number of files afterwards as before since there is the possibility that two files might end up with identical names and you will overwrite the first with the second. It might be an idea to check for existence of the destination file before the `mv` and decline to do the `mv` if the destination file exists.

Comment: Receiving error on sed command:  'extra characters at end of p command'.

Comment: @vikingfo04, fixed. BSD `sed` requires a trailing `;` after `p`, before `}`.

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -regex '[^P].*\.txt' -exec \
    sed -n "1 s|§ \([0-9]*\)\.\([0-9a-z-]*\) |mv '{}' P\1\2.txt|p" '{}' \
    \;
```

generates a shell script like

```
mv './file.txt' P6010-a.txt
```

that you can review and execute by appending `| sh`